# Acquiring state of a flag in set -o

Tags: bash, settings

How do we get state of a flag in set -o ... that has no direct alias
`set [-+]` , e.g.

```
set -o posix
```

or

```
set -o vi
```

?

not, e.g. `set -o errexit`  as its `set [-+] e` can be retrieved by

```
$ echo $-
```

then it'll be determined if letter e exists at the output string. Please help sincerely.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `set -o` without an argument:

```
$ set -o
allexport       off
braceexpand     on
emacs           off
errexit         off
errtrace        off
functrace       off
hashall         on
histexpand      on
history         on
ignoreeof       off
interactive-comments    on
keyword         off
monitor         on
noclobber       off
noexec          off
noglob          off
nolog           off
notify          off
nounset         off
onecmd          off
physical        off
pipefail        off
posix           off
privileged      off
verbose         off
vi              on
xtrace          off
```

or look at the [SHELLOPTS](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-SHELLOPTS) variable:

```
$ echo "$SHELLOPTS"
braceexpand:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor:vi
```

Comment: I looked at the manual, `set --help` doesn't include this information, but `man bash` does tell you, very tersely, that `-o` can be used on invocation of bash and that if "shopt_option is not supplied, the names and values of the shell options accepted by                  shopt  are  printed  on the standard output.".

Answer (score 1):

With `bash`:

```
if shopt -qpo posix; then
  echo "turned on";
else
  echo "turned off";
fi
```

See: `help set` and `help shopt`

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/269776/74329